# How to filter duplicate types from tuple C++

Tags: c++, tuples, metaprogramming

How does one filter duplicate types from a tuple?

For example:

```
using Tuple = std::tuple<int, double, int, double, std::string, std::string>
using FilteredTuple = without_duplicates<Tuple>;
```

In which without_duplicates is implemented in such a way that it generates the following FilteredTuple type:

```
std::tuple<int, double, std::string>
```

Comment: Do you also need to filter out duplicates if they aren't consecutive? E.g. should `without_duplicates<std::tuple<int, char, int>>>` be `std::tuple<int, char>`, or `std::tuple<int, char, int>`? The latter would likely be easier to accomplish.

Comment: Yes srry ill change the example to include that problem

Comment: @AndreasLoanjoe What's the actual use case you wan't to resolve with this? Sounds like a XY-problem for me.

Comment: I want to construct a vector of variants from a variadic template argument pack. But first I need to determine the variant type without duplicates. The problem above is just the minimal example of what I am struggling with.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work:

```
template <class Haystack, class Needle>
struct contains;

template <class Car, class... Cdr, class Needle>
struct contains<std::tuple<Car, Cdr...>, Needle> : contains<std::tuple<Cdr...>, Needle>
{};

template <class... Cdr, class Needle>
struct contains<std::tuple<Needle, Cdr...>, Needle> : std::true_type
{};

template <class Needle>
struct contains<std::tuple<>, Needle> : std::false_type
{};



template <class Out, class In>
struct filter;

template <class... Out, class InCar, class... InCdr>
struct filter<std::tuple<Out...>, std::tuple<InCar, InCdr...>>
{
  using type = typename std::conditional<
    contains<std::tuple<Out...>, InCar>::value
    , typename filter<std::tuple<Out...>, std::tuple<InCdr...>>::type
    , typename filter<std::tuple<Out..., InCar>, std::tuple<InCdr...>>::type
  >::type;
};

template <class Out>
struct filter<Out, std::tuple<>>
{
  using type = Out;
};


template <class T>
using without_duplicates = typename filter<std::tuple<>, T>::type;
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e17799d0ffaa0ac)

[[Godbolt]](https://godbolt.org/z/zb01q5)

It works by iteratively constructing the output tuple. Before each type is added, check (using the predicate `contains`) whether it's already in the output tuple or not. If not, it's added (the "else" branch of `std::conditional`), otherwise it's not added (the "then" branch of `std::conditional`).

Comment: For everybody else interested here is a link to a test: https://godbolt.org/z/zb01q5

Comment: @AndreasLoanjoe Happy to help, it's fun to wrestle such a challenge every once in a while and put my Prolog/Lisp lectures to use (as logical/functional programming is essentially what template metaprogramming is, albeit with weird syntax).

Comment: Yeah I have done some scheme in the past but the syntax can still be dazzling for these kind of operations in C++, passing on the Out argument was the aha moment for me in this one.

Comment: Small variant to delay instantiation in `conditional` to reduce number of instantiations: [Demo](https://cppinsights.io/s/edc7678b) (274 lines) versus [your](https://cppinsights.io/s/2124944b) (782 lines)

Answer (score 18):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct unique : std::type_identity<T> {};

template <typename... Ts, typename U, typename... Us>
struct unique<std::tuple<Ts...>, U, Us...>
    : std::conditional_t<(std::is_same_v<U, Ts> || ...)
                       , unique<std::tuple<Ts...>, Us...>
                       , unique<std::tuple<Ts..., U>, Us...>> {};

template <typename... Ts>
using unique_tuple = typename unique<std::tuple<>, Ts...>::type;
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0352fe0deb35adf)

Comment: Using `std::disjunction` instead of `||` may be a better choice due to short-circuiting.

Comment: And why use `std::type_identity`?

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to Boost, then this can be done directly using `boost::mp11::mp_unique<your_tuple_type>`.

For example:

```
{
  using not_unique = std::tuple<int, int, char, std::string, double, int>;
  using filtered = boost::mp11::mp_unique<not_unique>;
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::tuple<int, char, std::string, double>, filtered>);
}
{
  using already_unique = std::tuple<int, char, std::string, double>;
  using filtered = boost::mp11::mp_unique<already_unique>;
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::tuple<int, char, std::string, double>, filtered>);
}
```

[Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pbRqp0kx2qS57jkL)

Answer (score 4):

I have found it is often more easy to reason about 'if constexpr' statements, than it is to parse the std::conditional in my head.

To that end I have adjusted Piotr's answer to fit in that form:
[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e540f3466fc7c300)

```cpp
template < typename T, typename ...Rest >
constexpr auto make_unique_tuple( std::tuple< T, Rest... > )
{
    if constexpr ( ( std::is_same_v< T, Rest > || ... ) )
    {
        return make_unique_tuple( std::tuple< Rest... >{} );
    }
    else
    {
        if constexpr ( sizeof...( Rest ) > 0 )
        {
            using remaining = decltype( make_unique_tuple( std::tuple< Rest... >{} ) );
            return std::tuple_cat( std::tuple< T >{}, remaining{} );
        }
        else
        {
            return std::tuple< T >{};
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While I really like that answer and upvoted it, there are two things that should perhaps be noted:

- Passing the tuple as argument is superflous (could simply use the `template` parameter, which would enable use for types not proving `constexpr` constructor).

-If my understanding it correct, it may "reorder" your elements. For example, passing `int, float, int` will make `tuple<float, int>` and not `tuple<int, float>`.

Comment: The arguments will not be reordered, but only the last unique arguments remain, in their respective ordering.

Comment: Yes, " reorder " is probably not the correct term. I could not find the appropriate word for that (which is why I gave an example and quoted it).

Comment: Using the constexpr function approach is very nice and clean form of metaprogramming but be aware that it usually adds more requirements to the types. For example, in this case, all the types need to be default constructible and copyable.

Answer (score 3):

Piotr's code is very concise and should be prefered. Here an extended version for general variadic templated classes which works on C++17 (e.g. `std::variant` or custom containers):

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

// end of recursive call: tuple is forwared using `type`
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct unique_impl {using type = T;};

// recursive call: 1. Consumes the first type of the variadic arguments, 
//                    if not repeated add it to the tuple.  
//                 2. Call this again with the rest of arguments
template <template<class...> class Tuple, typename... Ts, typename U, typename... Us>
struct unique_impl<Tuple<Ts...>, U, Us...>
    : std::conditional_t<(std::is_same_v<U, Ts> || ...)
                       , unique_impl<Tuple<Ts...>, Us...>
                       , unique_impl<Tuple<Ts..., U>, Us...>> {};

// forward definition
template <class Tuple>
struct unique_tuple;

// class specialization so that tuple arguments can be extracted from type
template <template<class...>class Tuple, typename... Ts>
struct unique_tuple<Tuple<Ts...>> : public unique_impl<Tuple<>, Ts...> {};
```

## [Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ExhdhK6bE)

If you need C++11 you just need to replace the fold expression `(std::is_same_v<U, Ts> || ...)` to use a self-made `disjunction<...>` (see [cppreference possible implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/disjunction)).

Answer (score 0):

C++11 implementation, based on [Piotr Skotnicki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57528226/) and [SoilRos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62089731/) answers:

```cpp
#include <type_traits> // for std::false_type, std::conditional

namespace meta {

// Port of std::disjunction from C++14
// Based on: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/disjunction

template <typename ... Types>
struct disjunction
        : std::false_type
{};

template <typename B1>
struct disjunction<B1>
        : B1
{};

template <typename B1, typename ... Bn>
struct disjunction<B1, Bn...>
    : std::conditional<
        bool(B1::value),
        B1,
        disjunction<Bn...>
    >::type
{};

} // namespace meta


namespace meta {

/**
    # Example of usage

    @code{.cpp}
    template <typename ... Types>
    using unique_tuple = typename unique<std::tuple<>, Types ...>::type;

    unique_tuple<bool, int, float, int, int, float> tuple; // --> std::tuple<bool, int, float>

    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    template <typename ... Types>
    using unique_variant = typename unique<std::variant<>, Types...>::type;

    unique_variant<bool, int, float, int, int, float> var; // --> std::variant<bool, int, float>
    @endcode
*/


/**
    End of recursive call: tuple is forwared using `type`

    Note: In C++20 it may be implemented like:

    @code{.cpp}
    template <typename T, typename ... Types>
    struct unique : std::type_identity<T> {};
    @endcode
*/
template <typename T, typename ... Types>
struct unique {
    using type = T;
};

/**
    Recursive call:
      1. Consumes the first type of the variadic arguments,
         if not repeated add it to the tuple.
      2. Call this again with the rest of arguments

    Note: In C++17 it may be implemented by using fold-expression:

    @code{.cpp}
    template <
        template<class...> class Tuple, typename... TupleTypes,
        typename U, typename... Us
    >
    struct unique<Tuple<TupleTypes...>, U, Us...>
        : std::conditional<
            (std::is_same_v<U, TupleTypes> || ...)
            , unique_impl<Tuple<TupleTypes...>, Us...>
            , unique_impl<Tuple<TupleTypes..., U>, Us...>>::type
    {};
    @endcode
*/
template <
        template<class...> class Tuple, typename... TupleTypes,
        typename U, typename... Us
>
struct unique< Tuple<TupleTypes...> , U, Us...>
    : std::conditional<
        disjunction< std::is_same<U, TupleTypes> ... >::value
        , unique<Tuple<TupleTypes...>, Us...>
        , unique<Tuple<TupleTypes..., U>, Us...>
     >::type
{};

} // namespace meta
```

Compile-time tests/validation:

```cpp
#include <tuple>

namespace tests {

using namespace meta;

// No-types check
static_assert(std::is_same<
    unique< std::tuple<> >::type,
    std::tuple<>
>::value == true, "Test failed");

// Single type check
static_assert(std::is_same<
    unique< std::tuple<>, bool >::type,
    std::tuple<bool>
>::value == true, "Test failed");

// No-duplicates check
static_assert(std::is_same<
    unique< std::tuple<>, bool, int, float >::type,
    std::tuple<bool, int, float>
>::value == true, "Test failed");

// Single duplicate check
static_assert(std::is_same<
    unique< std::tuple<>, int, int>::type,
    std::tuple<int>
>::value == true, "Test failed");

// Multiple duplicates check
static_assert(std::is_same<
    unique< std::tuple<>, int, int, int, int, int >::type,
    std::tuple<int>
>::value == true, "Test failed");

// Few duplicates check
static_assert(std::is_same<
    unique< std::tuple<>, int, int,    float, float >::type,
    std::tuple<int, float>
>::value == true, "Test failed");

// Duplicates in the middle check
static_assert(std::is_same<
    unique< std::tuple<>, bool,    int, int, int, float, float, float,    double >::type,
    std::tuple<bool, int, float, double>
>::value == true, "Test failed");

// Duplicates mixed check
static_assert(std::is_same<
    unique< std::tuple<>, bool,    int, int, int,    float,   double, double,    int,    bool, bool>::type,
    std::tuple<bool, int, float, double>
>::value == true, "Test failed");

// Duplicates mixed check
static_assert(std::is_same<
    unique< std::tuple<>, bool, int, float,    bool, int, float >::type,
    std::tuple<bool, int, float>
>::value == true, "Test failed");

// Duplicated type-alias check
static_assert(std::is_same<
    unique< std::tuple<>, short, int, std::int16_t,    std::int32_t >::type,
    std::tuple<short, int>
>::value == true, "Test failed");

// Duplicated type-alias check
static_assert(std::is_same<
    unique< std::tuple<>, signed char, std::int8_t >::type,
    std::tuple<signed char>
>::value == true, "Test failed");

} // namespace tests
```

### [[Godbolt]](https://godbolt.org/z/rbTYras7K)