# C++ Take a union of the parameters in a parameter pack of variadic templates?

Tags: c++, templates

I've been writing a bit of code in C++ that involves a lot of metaprogramming; the code models a task that is defined at runtime by some series of nodes that take a number of inputs and, when run, produce some number of outputs. Inputs and outputs are linked in a directed graph. There's a bounded number of node types, which I'm storing in a variant, and each node class defines a static constexpr variable that, more or less, lists what types are input and output from that node. I'd like to be able to take a list of the classes of nodes and convert it into a list of the classes of data that are acted upon by the nodes.

To be more explicit, if I have a template that purely tracks some list of classes at compile-time like this:

```
template<class... Args>
struct ClassList{};
```

I want some sort of template that transforms list of lists like this:

```
ClassList<ClassList<int,int,double>, ClassList<double,char>, ClassList<char, char> >
```

into the union of the inner lists:

```
ClassList<int,double,char>
```

with no special requirements for order - except that each type appearing in the original lists appears exactly once in the final list - and if possible, I'd like to do this in a way that won't cause my compiler to explode. I know that I could, in theory, write a whole bunch of recursive templates that would join the lists into one and then remove duplicates, but that solution sounds a bit unsavory. Is there a better way?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55941964/how-to-filter-duplicate-types-from-tuple-c

Comment: I wanted to do some weird stuff (sorting on an array of `type_index`) with `typeid` but `type_index` is not `constexpr` :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution that filters types before adding them into the final list:

```
template<class... Ts>
struct class_list {};

template<class... Ts>
struct make_unique {
    using type = class_list<Ts...>;
};

template<class... Ts>
struct make_unique<class_list<>, Ts...> : make_unique<Ts...>{};

template<class U, class... Us, class... Ts>
struct make_unique<class_list<U, Us...>, Ts...> 
    : std::conditional_t<
          (std::is_same_v<U, Us> || ...) || (std::is_same_v<U, Ts> || ...), 
          make_unique<class_list<Us...>, Ts...   >,
          make_unique<class_list<Us...>, Ts..., U>> {};

template<class... Ts>
using make_unique_class_list = typename make_unique<Ts...>::type;

using T = make_unique_class_list<class_list<int, int, double>,
              class_list<double, char>, class_list<char, char>>;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, class_list<int, double, char>>);
```

Note that the following similarly looking solution also works but can be too slow, because it instantiates many unnecessary templates:

```
template<class U, class... Us, class... Ts>
struct make_unique<class_list<U, Us...>, Ts...> 
    : std::conditional<
          (std::is_same_v<U, Us> || ...) || (std::is_same_v<U, Ts> || ...), 
          typename make_unique<class_list<Us...>, Ts...   >::type,
          typename make_unique<class_list<Us...>, Ts..., U>::type> {};
```