# Extract a c++ variant type from a list of type names

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, std-variant

I am designing a pipeline class that needs to extract a `std::variant` from a list of distinct types in a filter class. For example:

```
template <typename T>
struct Filter {
  using type = T;
  // ...
}

template <typename... Filters>
struct Pipeline {
  
  // how to properly define the variant type?
  // std::variant<Filters::type...> buffer;

};
```

For example, if I have three different filter types:

```
Filter<int>, Filter<double>, Filter<std::string>
```

then, the variant should be `std::variant<int, double, std::string>`. However, I need to remove duplicate types in the variant, for example:

```
Filter<int>, Filter<double>, Filter<std::string>, Filter<int>
```

then, the variant should NOT be `std::variant<int, double, std::string, int>` but `std::variant<int, double, std::string>`. Additionally, I need to replace `void` with `std::monostate`. For example:

```
Filter<int>, Filter<double>, Filter<void>, Filter<int>, Filter<void>
```

then, the variant should be `std::variant<int, double, std::monostate>`.

How to design such a metaclass that can properly define the variant type based on the given type names `template <typename... Filters>` using c++17?

Comment: There's [How to filter duplicate types from tuple C++ - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55941964/how-to-filter-duplicate-types-from-tuple-c), the rest you probably is have to implement template metaprogramming as usual.

Comment: I don't think c++ compiler could directly do this. You may need to redesign your code with the help of `std::tuple`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [Piotr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57528226/11638718):

```
#include <variant>

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct unique { using type = T; };

template <typename... Ts, typename U, typename... Us>
struct unique<std::variant<Ts...>, U, Us...>
  : std::conditional_t<(std::is_same_v<U, Ts> || ...), 
                        unique<std::variant<Ts...>, Us...>, 
                        unique<std::variant<Ts..., U>, Us...>> {};

template <typename... Ts>
using variant_t = typename unique<
  std::variant<>, 
  std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<Ts, void>, std::monostate, Ts>...>::type;
```

then your `Pipeline` can be defined as:

```
template <typename T>
struct Filter {
  using type = T;
};

template <typename... Filters>
struct Pipeline {
  variant_t<typename Filters::type...> buffer;
};
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/9Pf78MqoK)

Comment: Thank you very much.