# From Variadic Arguments to its Inner Types as Variadic Arguments

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, variadic-templates

I am checking if variadic arguments are unique using the below:

```
template<class T, class... Ts>
constexpr bool is_unique_v = (!std::is_same_v<T, Ts>&& ...) && is_unique_v<Ts...>;

template<class T>
constexpr bool is_unique_v<T> = true;
```

I am trying to do the below (commented):

```
template<class B, class C>
class A
{
    using BT = B;
    using CT = C;
};

template<class... BorCs>
    requires is_unique_v<BorCs...>
class D
{
    using UT = std::tuple<BorCs...>;
};

//How can do the below?
template<class... As>
class E
{
    //N = size of As
    //using DT = D<Unique(As[0]::BT, As[0]::CT, ..., As[N]::BT, As[N]::CT)>; //The order here does not matter
};
```

I am not sure how I can do the above. Any ideas are welcomed!!

Comment: If order doesn't matter, you can do all the BTs followed by all the CTs: `D<Unique(typename As::BT..., typename As::CT...)>` but I'm not sure what `Unique` is meant to be

Comment: Thanks so much! Unique is in order for it to compile because of the requires i.e. Unique Types as the Bs and Cs could be of same type

Comment: so is that removing duplicate types?

Comment: Yes, so it compiles

Comment: Sounds like what you really want is something like `template <template <typename...> class X, typename ... Ts> struct Unique{ using type=/*X<Us...>*/; };` where `Us...` is the list of the same types as `Ts...` with duplicates removed. The rest of the question is a red herring.

Comment: I see, I can put unique tuple: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55941964/how-to-filter-duplicate-types-from-tuple-c